# Does the o.d.e $\dot{x}(t) = v-AA^Tx(t)$ has a unique globally asymptotical stable equilibrium

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is this true that if $AA^T$ is non-singular then the o.d.e $\dot{x}(t) = v-AA^Tx(t)$ has a unique globally asymptotical stable equilibrium. where $A$ is $m\times n$ matrix and $v$ is a $m \times 1$ vector.

Answer (score 1):

It is true. First of all $AA^T$ is symmetric. Hence all eigenvalues of $AA^T$ are real. Furthermore $AA^T$ is positive definite since for all $x$ we have:
\begin{align}
x^TAA^Tx=x^T(A^T)^TA^Tx = \Vert A^Tx\Vert^2\geq 0
\end{align}
But we also know that $AA^T$ is nonsingular hence for all $x\neq 0$ we have $xAA^Tx^T\neq 0$. This shows that $AA^T$ is positive definite and that all eigenvalues of $AA^T$ are strictly positive (why?).

Now there is a unique equilibrium, namely:
\begin{align}
x^* = (AA^T)^{-1}v
\end{align}
Furthermore the derivative of $F(x)=v-AA^Tx$ is equal to $F'(x)= -AA^T$. Hence all the eigenvalues of $F'(x)$ are negative (why?). Hence the equilibrium point is asymptotically stable.